# Fetching specific link that contains specific text

Tags: java, selenium

Using Selenium java, I have a list of links and I want to print only links that contains the text "Java". This is my code:

```
package Selenium3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Jobs {

static WebDriver driver;

public Jobs(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public static void con(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
    List<WebElement> element = 
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".position_title.ng-binding"));
    for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
    String elementText = element.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(elementText);
    }
}
```

}

How do I do it?

Comment: Try` if(elementText.contains("Java")) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains()` method on your String

```
public static void con(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
        List<WebElement> element = 
    driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".position_title.ng-binding"));
        for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
        String elementText = element.get(i).getText();
        if (elementText.contains("Java")) {
            System.out.println(elementText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solution is valid, but I want to add a couple of alternatives.

If all links with the word "Java" are relevant for your selection, you can use:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Java"));
```

The bonus here is that such selection conveys much better what you meant to select, and won't change if page structure changes. But it could be incorrect if much more links contain word "Java", than job titles (e.g. if page contains ads with the word Java in their links, etc)

Another possibility is to combine both CSS class and text with one selector:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(
    By. cssSelector(".position_title.ng-binding:contains(Java)"));
```

And you can also do that with xpath:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(
    By. xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'position_title ng-binding') and contains(text(), 'Java')]"));
```